# understanding http ajax requests in chrome developer tools

Tags: xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I'm not a developer but an internet marketer - so forgive me for what is I'm sure a very basic question.  In my career, it's useful when looking at website marketing to better understand what tools are used, such as Google Analytics for example.  Most of the time this is quite simple - just view source and you'll see in the source code the javascript snippet.

I use the ghostery plugin to make this a bit easier, but what I don't understand about http requests is how ghostery reports a technology as being used, such as the ad server DoubleClick for example, but I can't see any code in the source code that references Doubleclick. This happens a lot but it's most often with ad server technologies.

When I look using Chrome Dev Tools, I do in fact see that the call was made by viewing the Source tab.

My question is this and it's really a general question where I'm trying to better understand how calls are made back and forth between the browser and all the various servers and services:

How, in Chrome Tools do I find what code made the call to load the resource, such as DoubleClick. I can't find anything in the source code, which tells me I don't fully understand how interactions are working. 
 I think from search StackOverflow that is is a xmlhttp call but I'm not sure about that, maybe it's cookies - I just don't know how this is working.   At the end of the day, I don't like not understanding how this all works, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the write direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Network` panel, find your request of interest. The **Initiator** column will contain a reference to the code that has initiated loading the associated resource.